# onListItemClick doesn't get called in a ListActivity with a custom row layout

Tags: android

I have an activity that extends `ListActivity` with an `ArrayAdapter`:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> fileList = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.row, R.id.text, items);
setListAdapter(fileList);
```

It uses a custom layout for a row:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkbox"
        style="@style/CheckBox" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        style="@style/Label.Plain"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="50sp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical" />

</LinearLayout>
```

And there is `onListItemClick` is the activity:

```
@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
  // ...
}
```

It worked fine when my row consisted of a single `TextView`. But when I changed it to a layout, `onListItemClick` ceased being called. Why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The focus goes to the `CheckBox` and that way your item do not get the click event. Try modifying your XML like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkbox"
        style="@style/CheckBox"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        style="@style/Label.Plain"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="50sp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the bellow properties to the checkbox and textview

```
android:focusable="false"
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
android:clickable="false"
```

Answer (score 0):

When you have a widget like checkbox button radiobutton, then you have to add this propery in your listview element in the xml :-

```
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

Now your click listener will work and also your checkbox listener if you implement it.

Answer (score 0):

yes it is common question always asked,it happens because child controls of custom layout gets the click before list,so list doesn't responds on click. add `android:focusable=false;` this will allow list to listen click.

```
<CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkbox"
        android:focusable="false"
        style="@style/CheckBox" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        style="@style/Label.Plain"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="50sp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical" />
```